# Overlay of 3D surface with contours in Python / matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, surface

I want a numpy array plotted as a 3D surface and the zero contour line to be highlighted in a striking color. I use the following code to plot the surface (`k_mean` is the array to be plotted):

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X,Y=np.meshgrid(range(k_mean.shape[0]), range(k_mean.shape[1])) 
Z=k_mean
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1,linewidth=0., edgecolor=None, alpha=0.8, cmap=cm.nipy_spectral, antialiased=False)
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='z', offset=0, cmap=cm.nipy_spectral)
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='x', offset=0, cmap=cm.nipy_spectral)
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='y', offset=120, cmap=cm.nipy_spectral)
ax.set_xlim(0, 120)
ax.set_ylim(0, 120)
ax.set_zlim(0, 1)
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
plt.show()
```

Now I have added the following line that works fine for itself:
`cs=plt.contour(X,Y,Z,levels=[0], colors='g', linewidths=3)`

But depending on where I insert it, either only the surface plot or the contour line is plotted.

How can If fix it in the way that the zero contour line appears on top of the surface?